# How to route navbar search to a specific index view?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-5, ransack

I'm trying to implement a navbar search and have attempted to follow these solutions https://stackoverflow.com/a/19929707/5101493 and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52538766/5101493.

Unfortunately my navbar search only works when on the `/businesses` index page and not otherwise. After search submission the app stays on the same page instead of directing to `/businesses`.

How can I fix this? Here are my relevant files:

**application_controller**

```
before_action :set_global_search_variable

def set_global_search_variable
  @p = Business.search(params[:q])
end
```

**businesses_controller**

```
def index
  @businesses = @p.result(distinct: true).sort_by(&:name)
end

def search
  index
  render :index
end
```

**routes**

```
resources :businesses do
  collection do
    match 'search' => 'businesses#search', via: [:get, :post], as: :search
  end
end
```

**_header partial**

```
<form class="form-inline" style='display:show'>
 <%= search_form_for @p , url: search_businesses_path, :html => { method: :post } do |f| %>
   <%= f.search_field :name_cont, {placeholder: " Find a business...", class: 'form-control mr-sm-2'} %>
   <%= f.submit "Search", class: "btn look-red my-2 my-sm-0 navsearch" %>         
 <% end %>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a form inside another form. The outermost form is always routing to the current page.

Instead make the outermost form a div.

```
<div class="form-inline" style='display:show'>
 <%= search_form_for @p , url: search_businesses_path, :html => { method: :post } do |f| %>
   <%= f.search_field :name_cont, {placeholder: " Find a business...", class: 'form-control mr-sm-2'} %>
   <%= f.submit "Search", class: "btn look-red my-2 my-sm-0 navsearch" %>         
 <% end %>
</div>
```